# How do I flip one card and not all the cards in this functional based React code

Tags: reactjs

So I have a cool card select animation that I then flip front to back contents with.

My problem, is that when I select a card to display from my deck and it successfully floats up via my css animation. When I select the "flip" button....it flips all the cards card.front to card.back and not just the selected card.

I need the flip button to only flip the one card and not all the cards.

Here is the main AllCards component code...can you point me in the right direction?

```
import frontCard from '../../Images/frontCard.png'
import backCard from '../../Images/backCard.png'
import React from 'react'
import './AllCards.scss'
import {useEffect, useRef, createRef} from 'react'

export default function AllCards({ cards, cardNumber, setCardNumber, front, setFront, history, }) {

  const labelRef = useRef()

  useEffect(()=>{
     //run after component mounted
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(()=> {
     labelRef.current.click();//trigger click 1 seconds
    }, 1000)

    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
  },[])

  function onClickLabel(index) {
   // console.log("hiii"+index);
  }


  function flipCard() {
    //TODO flip only the card with id 1
    console.log("flipCard")
    if (front) {
      setFront(false)
    } else {
      setFront(true)
    }
  }



  // TODO - flip only one card.... not all cards at same time
  // TODO - Banner Top - fix responsiveness so words always  appear
  // TODO - Center layout on iPad Mini
  // TODO - Study Deck view - add thick boarder on "Back"
  // TODO - New row for "Flip" button

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {/* nav begins here */}
      <ul id="nav">
        <li className="lowercase">
          <label htmlFor="put-cards-down">(Restart)</label>
        </li>
        {cards.map((card, index) =>
          <li key={index}>
            {(index == 0) ? (
             <label id={`item-${index}`} ref={labelRef} onClick={onClickLabel(index)} htmlFor={`toggle-card-${index + 1}`}>
              one Card {index + 1}
             </label>
            ):(
             <label id={`item-${index}`} onClick={onClickLabel(index)} htmlFor={`toggle-card-${index + 1}`}>
              two Card {index + 1}
             </label>
            )}
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
      {/* front-card */}
      <h1 id="pen-title"></h1>
      <div id="pen-description">Click card number above to start</div>

      {/* deck-bottom? */}

      {cards.map((card, index) =>
        /* index === cardNumber - 1 ? ( */
          <React.Fragment key={index}>
            <input type="radio" name="cards" className="card-checkbox" id={`toggle-card-${index +1}`} />
            <div className="studycard card" id={index+1}>
              <div className="card-body">
                <div className="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
                  <div className="col-8">
                    <h5 className="card-title">
                      {`Card ${index + 1} of ${cards.length}`}
                    </h5>
                    <p className="card-text">{front ? card.front : card.back}</p>

                    <button className="btn btn-secondary mx-1" onClick={flipCard}>
                      Flip
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-4">
                    {
                      <img
                        src={front ? frontCard : backCard}
                        className="img-fluid"
                        alt="cards"
                      ></img>
                    }
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        /* ) : null, */
      )}

      <input type="radio" name="cards" className="card-checkbox" id="put-cards-down"/>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: While [my demo example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactive-state-updates-vuv8z7?file=/src/App.tsx) won't give you the answer to get your code working, it should at least give you an idea/hint on how to leverage state to individually update your cards.

Comment: Alternatively, here's an [another demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-reactive-state-updates-chby6s?file=/src/App.tsx) which simplifies the state management.